# Magnet pattern and overloaded methods

Tags: scala, implicit

There is a significant difference in how Scala resolves implicit conversions from "Magnet Pattern" for non-overloaded and overloaded methods.

Suppose there is a trait `Apply` (a variation of a "Magnet Pattern") implemented as follows.

```
trait Apply[A] {
 def apply(): A
}
object Apply {
  implicit def fromLazyVal[A](v: => A): Apply[A] = new Apply[A] {
    def apply(): A = v
  }
}
```

Now we create a trait `Foo` that has a single `apply` taking an instance of `Apply` so we can pass it any value of arbitrary type `A` since there an implicit conversion from `A => Apply[A]`.

```
trait Foo[A] {
  def apply(a: Apply[A]): A = a()
}
```

We can make sure it works as expected using REPL and [this workaround to de-sugar Scala code](https://gist.github.com/mpilquist/4ed3196e9ee4543c1847).

```
scala> val foo = new Foo[String]{}
foo: Foo[String] = $anon$1@3a248e6a

scala> showCode(reify { foo { "foo" } }.tree)
res9: String =    
$line21$read.foo.apply(
  $read.INSTANCE.Apply.fromLazyVal("foo")
)
```

This works great, but suppose we pass a *complex expression* (with `;`) to the `apply` method.

```
scala> val foo = new Foo[Int]{}
foo: Foo[Int] = $anon$1@5645b124

scala> var i = 0
i: Int = 0

scala> showCode(reify { foo { i = i + 1; i } }.tree)
res10: String =
$line23$read.foo.apply({
  $line24$read.`i_=`($line24$read.i.+(1));
  $read.INSTANCE.Apply.fromLazyVal($line24$read.i)
})
```

As we can see, an implicit conversion has been applied only on the last part of the complex expression (i.e., `i`), not to the whole expression. So, `i = i + 1` was strictly evaluated at the moment we pass it to an `apply` method, which is not what we've been expecting.

Good (or bad) news. We can make `scalac` to use the whole expression in the implicit conversion. So `i = i + 1` will be evaluated lazily as expected. To do so we (surprize, surprize!) we add an overload method `Foo.apply` that takes any type, but not `Apply`.

```
trait Foo[A] {
  def apply(a: Apply[A]): A = a()
  def apply(s: Symbol): Foo[A] = this
}
```

And then.

```
scala> var i = 0
i: Int = 0

scala> val foo = new Foo[Int]{}
foo: Foo[Int] = $anon$1@3ff00018

scala> showCode(reify { foo { i = i + 1; i } }.tree)
res11: String =
$line28$read.foo.apply($read.INSTANCE.Apply.fromLazyVal({
  $line27$read.`i_=`($line27$read.i.+(1));
  $line27$read.i
}))
```

As we can see, the entire expression `i = i + 1; i` made it under the implicit conversion as expected.

So my question is why is that? Why the scope of which an implicit conversion is applied depends on the fact whether or not there is an overloaded method in the class.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Now, that is a tricky one. And it's actually pretty awesome, I didn't know that "workaround" to the "lazy implicit does not cover full block" problem. Thanks for that!

What happens is related to *expected types*, and how they affect type inference works, implicit conversions, and overloads.

### Type inference and expected types

First, we have to know that type inference in Scala is bi-directional. Most of the inference works bottom-up (given `a: Int` and `b: Int`, infer `a + b: Int`), but some things are top-down. For example, inferring the parameter types of a lambda is top-down:

```
def foo(f: Int => Int): Int = f(42)
foo(x => x + 1)
```

In the second line, after resolving `foo` to be `def foo(f: Int => Int): Int`, the type inferencer can tell that `x` must be of type `Int`. It does so *before* typechecking the lambda itself. It propagates type information from the function application down to the lambda, which is a parameter.

Top-down inference basically relies on the notion of *expected type*. When typechecking a node of the AST of the program, the typechecker does not start empty-handed. It receives an expected type from "above" (in this case, the function application node). When typechecking the lambda `x => x + 1` in the above example, the expected type is `Int => Int`, because we know what parameter type is expected by `foo`. This drives the type inference into inferring `Int` for the parameter `x`, which in turn allows to typecheck `x + 1`.

Expected types are propagated down certain constructs, e.g., blocks (`{}`) and the branches of `if`s and `match`es. Hence, you could also call `foo` with

```
foo({
  val y = 1
  x => x + y
})
```

and the typechecker is still able to infer `x: Int`. That is because, when typechecking the block `{ ... }`, the expected type `Int => Int` is passed down to the typechecking of the last expression, i.e., `x => x + y`.

### Implicit conversions and expected types

Now, we have to introduce implicit conversions into the mix. When typechecking a node produces a value of type `T`, but the expected type for that node is `U` where `T <: U` is false, the typechecker looks for an implicit `T => U` (I'm probably simplifying things a bit here, but the gist is still true). This is why your first example does not work. Let us look at it closely:

```
trait Foo[A] {
  def apply(a: Apply[A]): A = a()
}

val foo = new Foo[Int] {}
foo({
  i = i + 1
  i
})
```

When calling `foo.apply`, the expected type for the parameter (i.e., the block) is `Apply[Int]` (`A` has already been instantiated to `Int`). We can "write" this typechecker "state" like this:

```
{
  i = i + 1
  i
}: Apply[Int]
```

This expected type is *passed down* to the last expression of the block, which gives:

```
{
  i = i + 1
  (i: Apply[Int])
}
```

at this point, since `i: Int` and the expected type is `Apply[Int]`, the typechecker finds the implicit conversion:

```
{
  i = i + 1
  fromLazyVal[Int](i)
}
```

which causes only `i` to be lazified.

### Overloads and expected types

OK, time to throw overloads in there! When the typechecker sees an application of an overload method, it has much more trouble deciding on an expected type. We can see that with the following example:

```
object Foo {
  def apply(f: Int => Int): Int = f(42)
  def apply(f: String => String): String = f("hello")
}

Foo(x => x + 1)
```

gives:

```
error: missing parameter type
              Foo(x => x + 1)
                  ^
```

In this case, the failure of the typechecker to figure out an expected type causes the parameter type not to be inferred.

If we take your "solution" to your issue, we have a different consequence:

```
trait Foo[A] {
  def apply(a: Apply[A]): A = a()
  def apply(s: Symbol): Foo[A] = this
}

val foo = new Foo[Int] {}
foo({
  i = i + 1
  i
})
```

Now when typechecking the block, the typechecker has *no expected type* to work with. It will therefore typecheck the last expression without expression, and eventually typecheck the whole block as an `Int`:

```
{
  i = i + 1
  i
}: Int
```

Only now, with an already typechecked argument, does it try to resolve the overloads. Since none of the overloads conforms directly, it tries to apply an implicit conversion from `Int` to either `Apply[Int]` or `Symbol`. It finds `fromLazyVal[Int]`, which it applies *to the entire argument*. It does not push it inside the block anymore, giving:

```
fromLazyVal({
  i = i + 1
  i
}): Apply[Int]
```

In this case, the whole block is lazified.

This concludes the explanation. To summarize, the major difference is the presence vs absence of an expected type when typechecking the block. With an expected type, the implicit conversion is pushed down as much as possible, down to just `i`. Without the expected type, the implicit conversion is applied a posteriori on the entire argument, i.e., the whole block.