# Multitype method argument for varargs

Tags: scala

Let's imagine a method where we can pass variables of `Any` type.

```scala
def myMethod(input: Any*) = {
  input.foreach(println)
}

myMethod("q", "w", "e", 1, 2, 3, true, false, ...)
```

Does Scala allow to **restrict types**, for example example: **only** `String` **and** `Integer`?

Comment: some time ago a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76648350/lists-contain-few-types-scala/76655220) was asked. I've replied it detailing [other approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76655220/7214091) different from the @SilvioMayolo's answer. Which one is better for your case depends on the project you are working on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scala 3 supports *union types*, which allow us to encode this constraint directly.

```
def myMethod(input: (String | Int)*) = {
  input.foreach(println)
}
```

In Scala 2, you can still do this with implicits, if you get a little clever. This is called the [magnet pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32064375/magnet-pattern-and-overloaded-methods). The idea is that we'll write one concrete implementation of our method, which takes instances of a trait we control, called our magnet, and then we'll write a bunch of implicits to take the types we *actually* care about and convert them into our magnet trait.

```
sealed trait MyMethodMagnet {
  def innerValue: Any
}

implicit class IntMagnet(override val innerValue: Int) extends MyMethodMagnet
implicit class StringMagnet(override val innerValue: String) extends MyMethodMagnet
```

Then write `myMethod` to take `MyMethodMagnet` instances, and Scala will automagically convert valid values to the appropriate type.

```
def myMethod(input: MyMethodMagnet*) = {
  input.foreach { (x) => println(x.innerValue) }
}
```

You still call it the same way, and Scala implicitly wraps everything in our magnet classes.

```
myMethod(1, "A")
```

Comment: Wow! It's a really nice pattern. Thanks for sharing and answering!